# Real world situation/model using (factored) higher degree polynomial function?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

(Form A)
$$y=3x^5+23x^4-7x^3+x^2-4x+9$$

(Form B) something in factored form
$$y=(x-1)^2(x+2)^5(x-5)^4(x+7)$$

2 part question:

1) Anyone know of examples where these types of functions arise?

2) Is there a situation where you build up form B from the component factors, instead of somehow arriving at form B by simply manipulating/factoring form A?  Something with inherent meaning from those zeros?

Comment: Not sure what you really are asking for but e.g. polynomial interpolation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial has factors where zeroes are explicit, but that might not be real world enough (due to the Runge phenomenon) or perhaps more abstract situtations as BCH codes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCH_code but there it could be debatable what the inherent meaning for the zeros are. At leat the real world sitation condition is fulfilled for BCH codes (CD/DVD/QR-code e.g.) but the example might be more complicated than what you looked for (which is not uncommon for real world).

Comment: Just any example or situation that results in a polynomial higher degree equation?